# WireCloud does not access marketplace

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I could manage to install a FIWARE instance but I cannot retrieve data from the FIWARE Marketplace.

I have been following this: [Forge.Fiware.org WireCloud](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Application_Mashup_-_Wirecloud_-_User_and_Programmer_Guide#Browsing_the_Marketplace)
but it just says : `Connection error: No resources retrieved.`

I'm using the URL : `https://marketplace.lab.fiware.org` as mentioned in the tutorial, but I notice that when I use it in my browser, I need to login first.  From the WireCloud instance, I have not been prompted to enter a login/password, is this the cause of the problem ? How can I solve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `http://130.206.81.113/FiwareMarketplace/v1/`, this is an old instance of the [Marketplace-RI](https://github.com/service-business-framework/Marketplace-RI) (although it is the one used by the Mashup & Store portal in FIWARE Lab).

In https://marketplace.lab.fiware.org you can find a recent instance of WMarket (currently v4.3.3). [WMarket](https://github.com/conwetlab/WMarket/) has replaced Marketplace-RI, but WireCloud has not been updated to support WMarket yet.

We have updated the installation guide, thanks :).