# Fiware wirecloud marketplace error

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

Trying to configure a marketplace in my wirecloud instance, I have this:

Connection error: No resources retrieved.

I see this in stackoverflow: [WireCloud does not access marketplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31287781/wirecloud-does-not-access-marketplace)

It's one year ago, but the problem is the same, and both of URLs (http://130.206.81.113/FiwareMarketplace/v1 and https://marketplace.lab.fiware.org) give the same result.

other url?

or where can I download mashups to install in my instance?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, we are not going to add support for [`WMarket`](http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/marketplace-wmarket) because it is going to be replaced by the [`Business API Ecosystem`](https://github.com/FIWARE-TMForum) GE (it should be released on September).

The old instance of the Marketplace GE used in the Mashup portal (`http://130.206.81.113/FiwareMarketplace/v1`) was shutdown as it was hosted in the FIWARE testbed (instead of being part of FIWARE Lab) and the testbed is not longer active.

We are working on integrating WireCloud with the Business API Ecosystem GE, we estimate to have it ready by the end of September. In the meantime you will have to download the WireCloud components from the [Store portal](https://store.lab.fiware.org/search/tag/widget) and installing them into WireCloud manually.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

> **Note:** Support for the Business API Ecosystem was released in several stages (using a mashup, etc), but currently is fully integrated in WireCloud. [Documentation](http://wirecloud.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.1/user_guide/#managing-marketplaces) on how to use that integration is available in WireCloud v1.1 onwards.